# a.bat is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch, batch-file

I have a simple batch file `a.bat` in dir `c:\users\ppast\onedrive\plocha\`

```
@echo off
rem this is remark
dir "c:\program files" > c:\list.txt
echo "program has completed"
```

I want to execute it from cmd

```
>cd c:\users\ppast\onedrive\plocha
>dir /b
... 
a.bat
...
>a.bat
'a.bak' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Here I want simply execute it, but the batch cannot find it (it is correct dir, the file exists and the only way, I can exe the file is `>a` {TAB} to autocomplete `>a.bak` {Enter}. Now it works). So it only works with autocomplete, but not if I specify relative path from the current dir (e.g. simple `a.bat`). Why? IS there a possible other program is messing with it? I have some environment variables, but delete them all, yet the issue persist. Is there a reason only autocomplete work?

Comment: Do you have show file extensions turned on? Could it be the file is called `a.bat.bak`?

Comment: This is not possible unless some installed product or add-on intervenes. Try to repeat it when booting from Safe mode, and please add a screenshot of a complete CMD session.

Comment: @spikey_richie yes, I have extension show enabled. That's why I specify full-relative path (once in the dir)

Comment: @harrymc the only extension installed is `https://www.autohotkey.com/` which is only used for keyboard shortcuts and should not even be engaged in command execution

Comment: @Herdsman Unless you've manually opened `cmd`, the default terminal on Windows 10 is `powershell`, and Powershell requires a path to execute a script, so you'd need to issue `.\a.bat` || `cmd /c a.bat` or issue it with the full path: `$env:userprofile\onedrive\plocha\a.bat` || `cmd /c %userprofile%\onedrive\plocha\a.bat`